# How to use Two Toggle buttons on same page having same function with different css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have been trying to hard to add 2 Toggle Buttons having different styles (css) on Menu Bar and footer page. They are to be used for night and dark mode.

However when I use

```
onclick="themeToggle()" id="theme-switcher"
```

for both of the buttons, only one of them works.

This is my [Toggle Buttons Test Page.](https://freeairdrop.io/airdrop/bannertest2.html)

This is the js which is being used :

```
 var tSwitcher = document.getElementById('theme-switcher');
let element = document.body;

 let onpageLoad = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "";
 if(onpageLoad != null && onpageLoad  == 'dark-mode'){
      tSwitcher.checked = true;
 } 
 element.classList.add(onpageLoad);


function themeToggle(){
      if(tSwitcher.checked){
          localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark-mode');
            element.classList.add('dark-mode');
        } else {
          localStorage.setItem('theme', '');
            element.classList.remove('dark-mode');
        }
    }
```

This is the code for Two Toggle buttons

```
    <label class="switcher">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="themeToggle()" id="theme-switcher">
    <div>
    <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left arrow"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
    </div>
    </label>
```

```
 <label class="switch" style="padding: 23px 0;">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="themeToggle()" id="theme-switcher">
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Kindly help me in solving the issue with the code as well.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The reason they're not working is because IDs are always unique. You should use different IDs.

Comment: @neeraj,  please come to chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using ID in `<input type="checkbox" onclick="themeToggle()" id="theme-switcher">`, which you repeat in other `checkbox`. so only first ID in the DOM will be taken.

Change your `<input type="checkbox" onclick="themeToggle()" id="theme-switcher">`

To

`<input type="checkbox" onclick="themeToggle()" class="theme-switcher">`

And update the below code

Note: dont repeat ID

```
var tSwitcher = document.getElementsByClassName('theme-switcher');
let element = document.body;

let onpageLoad = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "";
if (onpageLoad != null && onpageLoad == 'dark-mode') {
        for(let i = 0; i<tSwitcher.length; i++){
                tSwitcher[i].checked = true;    
    }

}

if(onpageLoad) element.classList.add(onpageLoad);
```

So update your `themeToggle()` to

```
  function themeToggle() {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark-mode');
      element.classList.add('dark-mode');
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', '');
      element.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is working, but now the button on Menu Bar gets back to off position by default on page refresh @Akhil Aravind

Comment: does this happens when you reload the page ??

Comment: Yes on reload of page

Comment: This wasn't happening before

Comment: Thanks the code is working. Can you please move to chat. I have one more question @Akhil Aravind –

Comment: I would be waiting for the chat @Akhil Aravind

Comment: @neeraj I cant see you in chat,

Comment: Due to my lower reputation I can't move to chat @Akhil Aravind

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot have two or more elements with the same id.

To detect what button is being clicked you can pass the event to the function as argument like this.

```
onclick="themeToggle(event)" class="switcher" id="theme-switcher-2"
```

Once you have the event you can get the object that has fired it (In your case the button) like this.

```
    function themeToggle(event){
          var tSwitcher = event.target;
          if(tSwitcher.checked){
              localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark-mode');
                element.classList.add('dark-mode');
            } else {
              localStorage.setItem('theme', '');
                element.classList.remove('dark-mode');
            }
    }
```

**EDIT**

To set the default behaviour properly you have to add `class="switcher"` to each button and do this.

```
var tSwitchers = document.querySelectorAll('.switcher'));
let onpageLoad = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "";
tSwitchers.forEach((element) => {
    if(onpageLoad != null && onpageLoad  == 'dark-mode'){
       element.checked = true;
    } 
});
```

Comment: This is working, but now the button on Menu Bar gets back to off position by default on page refresh @Sapikelio

Comment: This wasn't happening before

Comment: I know. I've omitted this part. However, give me a minute and I'll solve it

Comment: Sure, Thanks for help

Comment: you can set `checked="true"` on your buttons

Comment: But now, it's default postion is towards night side only.

Comment: Oh sorry you have a custom behaviour to set the side. My faut! Let me change it

Comment: sure, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you are using getElementById it will return the first occurrence of that id from dom, and as you are having same id on both button it is updating the first button every time.
Instead, you can except event object, in click function, and assign event.target to get the button element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same ID for two or more HTML elements. Also, once you want to use this functionality in multiple elements, I strongly recommend you to **not** use `onclick` inline. Instead, you can get all switchers from your page and add a listener to them:

#### Get all switchers in your page

```
const switchers = document.querySelectorAll('.switcher');
```

#### Apply the click event listener on them

```
switchers.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        themeToggle(event);
    });
});
```

#### Finally, you must add the `switcher` class to all elements

```
<input type="checkbox" id="theme-switcher-1" class="switcher">
<input type="checkbox" id="theme-switcher-2" class="switcher">
<input type="checkbox" id="theme-switcher-3" class="switcher">
```

Using this approach, you can use this method all over your website or application and it's also easier to maintain.

**Update**: you should adjust the themeToggle() method like so:

```
function themeToggle(event){
  var tSwitcher = event.target;
  if(tSwitcher.checked){
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark-mode');
    tSwitcher.classList.add('dark-mode'); // changed element to tSwitcher
    console.log('Dark mode is on');
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', '');
    tSwitcher.classList.remove('dark-mode'); // changed element to tSwitcher
    console.log('Dark mode is off');
  }
}
```

#### Example snippet

**Obs.:** You should adjust it into your code. I had to comment localStorage because it didn't work here.

```js
const switchers = document.querySelectorAll('.switcher');
console.log(switchers);
switchers.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        themeToggle(event);
    });
});
function themeToggle(event){
  var tSwitcher = event.target;
  if(tSwitcher.checked){
    //localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark-mode');
    tSwitcher.classList.add('dark-mode');
    console.log('Dark mode is ON on ' + tSwitcher.id);
  } else {
    //localStorage.setItem('theme', '');
    tSwitcher.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    console.log('Dark mode is OFF on ' + tSwitcher.id);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="theme-switcher-1" class="switcher"><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="theme-switcher-2" class="switcher"><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="theme-switcher-3" class="switcher">
```

Comment: When I used the "Full working snippet" my page could not turn to Dark

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's not actually "full working". You should adjust your code.