# I want the CSS of a page to change when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, innerhtml

I found how you could do this with individual elements but I couldn't find anything that would change the the body CSS of a page. I am trying to make a thing where it will switch between light and dark mode when you click the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<button style="background-color: #252525;
border: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: white;
color: white; 
padding: 10px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none; 
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;  
font-weight: bold;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;" id="changethemebutton" onclick="changeTheme()">Change Theme</button>
```

```
function changeTheme() {
document.getElementById(".background").style.background = "black";
}
</script>
<style>
body{
    background-color:white
}
</style>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Two Toggle buttons on same page having same function with different css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60224350/how-to-use-two-toggle-buttons-on-same-page-having-same-function-with-different-c)

Comment: Thanks for `validation` ;) Please don't forget to `upvote` **all** helpfull answers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to set a dark-mode on your website is to toggle a class `.dark-mode` on your body using javascript and then stylize it using css:

```css
body {
  /* light-mode styles */
  background-color: white;
}

body.dark-mode {
  /* dark-mode styles */
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button style="background-color: #252525;
border: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: white;
color: white; 
padding: 10px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none; 
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;  
font-weight: bold;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;" id="changethemebutton" onclick="changeTheme()">Change Theme
</button>

<script>
  function changeTheme() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');  // <-- Toogle dark-mode class to <body>
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to target an element with a class using an incorrect method. [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) targets elements with a specified `id`. If you're trying to target a class, the most ideal method to do this with is [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
document.querySelector(".background").style.background = "black";
```